# ANOVA factor warning and no p value

Tags: r

I am doing one way ANOVA for a dataset and I am showing some rows here:-

```
Number  Call    Weight
1   X   33.29
2   Y   88.22
3   Y   70.19
4   Y   69.25
5   X   73.26
6   X   56.18
7   Y   16.19
8   Y   20.21
9   Y   50.26
10  X   95.29
```

I did anova using:-

```
aov <- aov(data$Weight ~ data$Call)
```

But it does not give any p value. I am also getting:-

```
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Look at the output of `str(data)`.

Comment: If Edwards comment didn't give you the needed hint to solve your problem please put the output of `str(data)` and `dput(head(data))` in an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code on these data and it works without issue. Try to check `str` of your data.  Most probably issue is that `Weight` is factor in your case and you need to change it to numeric with `as.numeric()`.

```
   dta <- read.table(text=
   "Number,  Call,    Weight
    1,   X,   33.29
    2,   Y,   88.22
    3,   Y,   70.19
    4,   Y,   69.25
    5,   X,   73.26
    6,   X,   56.18
    7,   Y,   16.19
    8,   Y,   20.21
    9,   Y,   50.26
    1,0  X,   95.29", header=T, sep=",")

    summary(aov(dta$Weight ~ dta$Call))
```

Result

```
Call:
   aov(formula = dta$Weight ~ dta$Call)

Terms:
                dta$Call Residuals
Sum of Squares   352.450  6303.466
Deg. of Freedom        1         8

Residual standard error: 28.07015
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

result for `str(dta)`

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Number: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
 $ Call  : Factor w/ 3 levels "   X","   Y",..: 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 3
 $ Weight: num  33.3 88.2 70.2 69.2 73.3 ...
```